# How to center DIVs with float: left; in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, center

I am fighting with this stuff some time already and cannot figure it out:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div style="float: left;">xxx</div>
    <div style="float: left;">xxx</div>
    <div style="float: left;">xxx</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot center those 3 **float: left;** DIVs... (I don't want to use hard width for them).

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Give your `.container` some `width` anduse `margin: auto;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4 offset4" style="float: left; text-align: center">xxx</div>
    <div class="span4 offset4" style="float: left; text-align: center">xxx</div>
    <div class="span4 offset4" style="float: left; text-align: center">xxx</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another possible solution would be creating custom class:

CSS:

```
.centered {
     float: none;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="span4 offset4 centered"> xxx </div>
```

Comment: What I didn't notice -- the DIVs are next to each other in one row, not 1 DIV on a single row.

Comment: If you want them to be on a single row, just use `clear:both`. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in bootstrap:

```
`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="span offset" style="float: left; text-align: center">----</div>

          <div class="span offset" style="float: left; text-align: center">----</div>

          <div class="span offset" style="float: left; text-align: center">----</div>

    </div>  </div>`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).